# "Consistence" and "consistency"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, suffixes

What is the relation and difference between the nouns *consistence* and *consistency*?

For example, which one should be used in the following sentence?

> Although he has passed the exam, he is suggested to take the next one,
>   because they would like to test his **consistence/consistency**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OED, both *consistence* and *consistency* are valid nouns. *Consistence* originally had many meanings, which include:

- Standing or remaining still, quiescence; state of rest. Obs.
- Continuance, endurance; continuing state
- A settled condition of affairs. Obs.
- concr. Matter dense enough to cohere. Obs. or poet.
- The degree of firmness with which the particles of a substance cohere; degree of density. (Usually of more or less viscous liquids.)
- consistency

As you can see, many of its definitions (of which there are 8 listed) are now obsolete. The last recorded use of *consistence* to mean *consistency* was in 1878. *Consistency* has now taken over many of these meanings, and is used far more often than *consistence*. Using *consistence* would not be incorrect, but it is an archaic form of a word that many people would not recognize today.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you want to be a couple of centuries out of date, use **consistency**, [like everyone else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consistence,consistency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

[image: Graph shows "consistence" decrease over time to nothing while "consistency" has increased]

Comment: I don't want, but the dictionary I looked up in did not tell me that. Before I looked it up in a dictionary, I thought a word ending in `-y` is most likely not a noun but an adjective. I wonder if it is true?

Comment: most dictionaries are pretty bad at telling you the current state of a language. they lag behind reality at least 10 years at best, 50-100 on average.

Comment: @myqlarson: Thanks! Is it true that a word ending in -y is most likely  an adjective than a noun?

Comment: dunno. let's see: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40572/is-it-true-that-a-word-ending-in-y-is-most-likely-an-adjective-than-a-noun

Answer (score 5):

*Consistence* isn't a word anymore. [It died](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consistence,%20consistency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Use *consistency*.

Answer (score 2):

One property of concrete is described in accordance with Eurocodes (BS EN 1992-1-1:2004) in terms of consistence.  Under previous British Stadards the word workability was used.  Consistence is measured by tests such as the slump test which indicate the way in which the material holds together and flows under its own weight.  It is a technical term and in no way incorrect or obsolete.